# How to change order total price in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop, payment

I'm creating loyalty points Module in prestashop.
My question is, How can i deduct specific amount from total price  in order-payment.tpl page?
I want to use that loyalty point and deduct it from order total price and use that price for forward process.
Please don't suggest to deduct in "tpl" file.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create CartRule for each user classes/CartRule.php